# What does -CHEAD mean in git commit?

Tags: git, github, git-commit

On a [GitHub documentation page](https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/removing-files-from-a-repositorys-history), I saw the following command:

> ```
> $ git commit --amend -CHEAD
> # Amend the previous commit with your change
> ```

I've used the command `git commit --amend` before, but I've yet to come across the `-CHEAD` argument. What does `-CHEAD` mean in this context, and how does it differ from `--no-edit`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [docs for `git commit`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit)

> `-C <commit>`
> `--reuse-message=<commit>`
> Take an existing commit object, and reuse the log message and the authorship information (including the timestamp) when creating the commit.

`HEAD` is the latest commit in your current history (normally your current branch).

This means, that you use the same commit message as the commit you are amending.

Docs for `--no-edit`:

> Use the selected commit message without launching an editor. For example, `git commit --amend --no-edit` amends a commit without changing its commit message.

According to those docs, `-C` will reuse "authorship information (including the timestamp)" while `--no-edit` will not.

Answer (score 7):

`-CHEAD` (which I would generally spell as `-C HEAD` instead) is *unnecessary* here, but its meaning is simple enough.  As [the `git commit` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit) notes, the `-C` option is short for `--reuse-message`:

> `-C <commit>`
> `--reuse-message=<commit>`
>       Take an existing commit object, and reuse the log message and the authorship information (including the timestamp) when creating the commit.

This is similar to the `-c` (lowercase) option, with one simple difference:

> `-c <commit>`
> `--reedit-message=<commit>`
>       Like `-C`, but with `-c` the editor is invoked, so that the user can further edit the commit message.

So `-C commit` is equivalent to `-c commit --no-edit`, or, if you prefer, swap the case of the `c` option and add `--edit`.

The name `HEAD`, in all uppercase, works as described in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions):

> `HEAD` names the commit on which you based the changes in the working tree

(or equivalently, the currently-checked-out commit).  So `-C HEAD` means to take the commit message from the current commit, without editing it.

With `--amend`, `--no-edit` means to take the commit message from the current commit, without editing it, and `--edit` means to take the commit message from the current commit, but stop to edit it.  So this is exactly equivalent *for `--amend`*.  For other commit options, the `-C`, `-F`, or `-m` option specifies the source of the initial commit message that may either be edited or not-edited as specified.